# What are the JSON mapper libraries supported by Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson, spring-data-rest

The Jackson library is the default integrated JSON mapper library with Spring Boot. I want to know what other libraries are available or integrated with Spring Boot, and how to implement them in our Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot has integrated with 3 json mapper api

- Jackson(default)
- Gson
- JSON-B

If we want to use for example Gson then simply add below dependency in your pom file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But we already have by default Jackson implemented which we can exclude either using maven or pragmatically

**Using maven**

In pom file add exclusion for starter-json under exclusions tag

```
<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

**programmatically**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})
public class GsonSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GsonSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```